# IK Bone act weird with control bone and does a 180° rotation

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics

when I try to position my control bone from my armature the whole construct makes a 180° roation which I don't want.

[image]

But the pose that my object should do looks like this and I can't get it this way.
[image]

Since I'm new to IK I have no idea how to solve this.
Here are a few more pictures from the bones in edit mode and the IK propertie window.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I call this "IK twitch".  Avoid angle limits.  Avoid angles that are distant from rest pose; adjust rest pose to be the median of your anticipated transformations.  Avoid manually rotating the bones or using constraints/drivers to do so, avoid stiffness.  Any more suggestions, I'd need a file to say.

Comment: did u try pole target?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is kinda embarrasing for me, but the solution was to **reduce the Chain Length by one inside the IK properties**.
I'm thankful for the advice and help I got, but this was just the Chain length that caused the problem.